# Can't find Firefox update in Ubuntu Update Manager

Tags: updates, firefox, update-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and my Firefox version is 14.0.1. Since because of this version I can't install Firebug. So for upgrading it I searched at the Help->About in the browser window, but there is no update option. Then I searched in the Ubuntu Update Manager, and there are listed very many updates, but I didn't find "Firefox browser update". I'm new to Ubuntu, and I don't know how to work in the terminal so I haven't tried that.

Comment: So, why don't you install updates offered by the update manager?

Comment: i just want to upgrade firefox immediately for my work to continue. dont have time to wait for the whole updates to complete. thats why..sir i asked for FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update just Firefox, you could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install firefox
```

I'd recommend installing the rest of the updates at your earliest convenience.

Comment: that worked and now my ff is v26